# Find the column number in a spreadsheet according to the letter that identifies it

Tags: python

Google Sheets maintains an identity for each column that follows this pattern:

```
col 1 = A
col 26 = Z
col 27 = AA
col 52 = AZ
```

To know the column number according to the id I do it like this:

```python
import itertools
import string

col_values = 'AA'

def col_letter_to_num(col, col_abs=False) -> int:
    col_num = col
    if col_num < 0:
        return None
    col_num += 1
    col_str = ''
    col_abs = '$' if col_abs else ''
    while col_num:
        remainder = col_num % 26
        if remainder == 0:
            remainder = 26
        col_letter = chr(ord('A') + remainder - 1)
        col_str = col_letter + col_str
        col_num = int((col_num - 1) / 26)
    return col_abs + col_str

if isinstance(col_values, int):
    col_num = col_values
elif isinstance(col_values, str) and not any(x in col_values for x in list(string.digits)):
    for i in itertools.count(start=0):
        if col_letter_to_num(i) == col_values:
            col_num = i+1
            break
else:
    col_num = 'ERROR'

print(col_num)
```

I brought the code for review in order to learn to discover the most correct and professional methods to reach the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first `-> int` is inaccurate since you sometimes `return None`; so that should be `-> Optional[int]`. However: don't `return None`. Raise a `ValueError`.

`col_letter_to_num`, first of all, has a lie as its name. It doesn't convert column letters to a column number; it does the opposite. As written it's backwards and should entirely go away, and rather than your `for i in count()` that attempts every index until there's a match, just find the index directly by doing math on the given string.

Producing the string `'ERROR'` is a bad idea. Raise an exception if there's a data problem.

The behaviour of using `isinstance(int)` to default to a no-op suggests a problem elsewhere in the code where you don't actually know what kind of variable you're holding. This is a hidden problem and a code smell. Do not apply this default. Elsewhere in the code, it should be well-defined enough that you always know that you're holding a string when you need one. In your function, require that the argument is a string.

Your `not any` validation can be greatly simplified: instead of looping through a generator and checking each character's membership in `digits`, just check for `isalpha()` on the entire string.

### Suggested

```py
def col_letter_to_num(col_values: str) -> int:
    if not isinstance(col_values, str):
        raise TypeError(f'col_values must be a str, got {type(col_values).__name__}')
    if not col_values.isalpha():
        raise ValueError(f'col_values must be alphabetic, got {col_values}')

    col_num = 0
    for c in col_values:
        col_num = col_num*26 + 1 + ord(c.upper()) - ord('A')

    return col_num


def main() -> None:
    for example in (
        'A', 'Z', 'AA', 'AZ', 'ba', 'BIG',
    ):
        print(f'col {col_letter_to_num(example)} = {example}')

    for bad in ('A5', 83):
        try:
            col_letter_to_num(bad)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Output

```
col 1 = A
col 26 = Z
col 27 = AA
col 52 = AZ
col 53 = ba
col 1593 = BIG
col_values must be alphabetic, got A5
col_values must be a str, got int
```

Comment: If I may, just missed one detail, to accept int (```if isinstance(col_values, int): return col_values```). But if the value is int, it returns the same value sent. For example, if the value is 5, then it returns 5. Thanks for support @Reinderien!

Comment: @DigitalFarmer don't do that. Re-read the _default to a no-op_ paragraph.

Comment: Sorry for my English, when translating I misunderstood what was said, I understand it perfectly now, sorry!

Comment: No problem, glad to help!